# Switch case statement not rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My goal is to render a component based on the `type` prop I am passing to the component.

Here is how I am passing the `type` prop to the component:

```js
export default function SearchListItem({
  type,
}) {
```

And here is my switch case statement:

```js
const notificationComponent = (type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case type == 1:
        return <Text>1</Text>;
      case type == 2:
        return <Text>2</Text>;
      case type === 3:
        return <Text>3</Text>;
      case type === 4:
        return <Text>3</Text>;

      default:
        return <Text>No project</Text>;
    }
  };
```

And here is how I am rendering the component on the page:

```js
  <Title>{notificationComponent(type)}</Title>
```

Here is how I am passing the props in from the parent component:

```js
<ActivityListItem type={3} />
<ActivityListItem type={4} />
```

Currently, the component is only returning the `No project` case although I am passing in props that should match the different cases. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @jnpdx Just updated the code

Comment: Looks like you need to call `notificationComponent(type)`? You're calling it with no arguments right now.

Comment: @jnpdx You asked how I am passing in the props

Comment: @maazadeeb Hmmm, still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case statements are wrong. Only specify the value, not a comparison.

```
switch (type) {
    case type == 1:
        return <Text>1</Text>;
    ...
}
```

wouldn't do anything, as `type == 1` would get evaluated to `true` and `type` is not equal to `true`.

Instead, do:

```
switch (type) {
    case 1:
        return <Text>1</Text>;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It was luck, though. Next time post a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), to eliminate the luck factor and reduce the frustration of the people trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

This may well mean that your var `type` is not defined or passed correctly.

You may want to `console.log` this var and see what it really is.